# Why is this jQuery syntactically wrong?

Tags: jquery, firebug, datatables

I have a jQuery/[datatables](http://datatables.net/index) app I'm writing, and I'm getting the following Firebug JS error:

```
TypeError: $("#my-datatable").datatable is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

"fnServerParams" : function(serverParams) {
```

When I click the on the error it brings me to the following jQuery/datatbale code I wrote:

```
$("#my-datatable").datatable( {
    "sAjaxSource" : "/widgets/doSomething",
    "fnServerParams" : function(serverParams) {
        serverParams.push(
            {
                "name" : "provider",
                "value" : token
            }
        );
    }
});
```

It's complaining about the line that read:

> "fnServerParams" : function(serverParams) {

How am I using this incorrectly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the line it's complaining about

Comment: To anyone who has downvoted this - please let me know why! Is this a duplicate? If so please provide a link to the dupe! Does this show a lack of research? I don't think it does - I posted all the code, the error messages, and I'm clearly new to datatbales and can't figure out why this is not working. I come here to learn, so please, if you're going to downvote my question, please tell me why so I can ask better questions in the future!

Comment: @lc - whether or not its complaining about that line, that's the line Firebug takes me to when I click the error message in the console. It looks like valid JS to me, but I figured I'd include it to be thorough.

Comment: This should not qualify as "too localized" of a question. There is bad JavaScript syntax somewhere in here, and I can't find it. I don't think that's too localized.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be taking you to that particular line. Maybe it's a bug in Firebug? The error sounds to me it's complaining about the .datatable() call - possibly because it should be `dataTable()` with a big T (looking at your link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error is '$("#my-datatable").datatable is not a function', this usually means the source code for the function has not been included. Are you including whatever source js files needed for this before calling the function?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="somewhere.js"></script>
```

If you are already including this, the other thing to check would be to make sure the call happens when the DOM is ready. This can be done with $(document).ready or $(function(){}) like so:

```
$(function(){
    $("#my-datatable").datatable({...})
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Seth (+1) - however, I checked both items: (1) I am including the `jquery.dataTables.js` in the `<head>` tag (as in your example), and verified that the browser can access this script on the client-side (by Viewing Page Source and clicking on the link), and (2) yes, this is happening inside my big `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` function. Any other ideas? Any way I can debug from here? Thanks again!

Comment: If you are using the plugin from http://datatables.net/, it looks like the function should be 'dataTable' (capital 't') instead of 'datatable'. If not, can you post a link to the datatable code?